# Tridion is throwing an error message when user attempt to preview or compare a page in Tridion 2009

Tags: templating, 2009

We are using Tridion SP1 2009 .We are facing the below issue when we are trying to preview or compare page against `Expandable CT` and `Multiple CT` the following error is thrown:

```
(2147747185) An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 13, position 198.
Unable to get rendered content of Component (tcm:15-10282).
Unable to retrieve rendered data from Component Presentation.
Unable to retrieve rendered data from Component Presentation.

   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseEntityName()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributeValueSlow(Int32 curPos, Char quoteChar, NodeData attr)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributes()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument.LoadFromReader(XmlReader reader, XmlSpace space)
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument..ctor(XmlReader reader, XmlSpace space)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryContext.ConstructDocument(Object dataSource, String uriRelative, Uri uriResolved)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryContext..ctor(XmlQueryRuntime runtime, Object defaultDataSource, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argList, WhitespaceRuleLookup wsRules)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryRuntime..ctor(XmlQueryStaticData data, Object defaultDataSource, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argList, XmlSequenceWriter seqWrt)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlSequenceWriter results)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlWriter writer, Boolean closeWriter)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(XmlReader contextDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlWriter results)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Transform(XmlReader input, XsltArgumentList arguments, XmlWriter results, XmlResolver documentResolver)
   at Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.XsltMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Compound.CompoundTemplateMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template templateToTransform, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformPackage(Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformItem(Template template, IdentifiableObject itemToRender)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.TemplatingRenderer.Render(ResolvedItem resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget target, RenderedItem renderedItem, RenderContext renderContext)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderEngine.Render(ResolvedItem resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget target, RenderContext context)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderEngine.Render(IdentifiableObject item, Template template, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget target, RenderContext context)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.ComWrapper.RenderEngineFacade.RenderItemWithTemplate(IdentifiableObject item, Template template, String legacyRenderInstruction)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.ComWrapper.RenderEngineFacade.RenderComponentPresenation(UserContext userContext, String componentXml, String componentTemplateXml, String instruction)
UtilitiesPublish.RenderComponentPresentation
ComponentPresentation.Render
Component.Render
Request.Render
```

We tried debugging using template builder but we couldn't find exactly where the entity name is defined .

Any help here is well appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be an error with your XSLT (XSLT Mediator) - Could you add the offending XSLT TBB to your question - My best guess is that you have some kind of special symbol (copyright,ampersand, no-breaking space or something) in your XSLT.

Comment: Is there by any chance an ampersand in your XSLT TBB that isn't properly escaped?

Comment: Looks like there's an entity reference in the XML that isn't defined. Is there any chance you could post the XML of the Component and it's template? If it's too sensitive, you might want to go through Customer Support instead.

Comment: hi - while debugging using template builder, its giving the following stacktrace.. and at that particular line, I could see this piece of line:  <a href="/views/asp/preview.asp?previewMode=Static&ItemType=16&ItemURI=tcm:15-38040&FromWF=False"

Answer (score 1):

> Unable to get rendered content of Component (tcm:15-10282)

Looks like something is wrong with this Component and/or its associated template.

- If you preview the page without it, do you get the same error?
- Has the schema changed?
- Has anything changed in your XSLT template?

You may get better suggestions if you post your XSLT and the XML of the component in question.

Comment: Hi Nuno - The preview is working fine without it. No, the schema is not changed. The only peculiar behaviour we could find is, if we remove anchor tags from the component, then the preview is working fine. With anchor tags, when we see the xml using visual studio - it says "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink:href attribute is not declared. Is there any specification we need to use the anchor tags?

Comment: Currently, we are using the anchor tags like this: <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><a title="Auto-Renew Sports Subscriptions" xlink:href="tcm:10-36988" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">auto renews </a>at a special rate each year, unless canceled before the season starts.</p>

Comment: Looks like it's missing `http://www.`  from that namespace declaration. That's really odd, I'd contact Customer Support right now.

Comment: yeah, this issue is running from past 3 months with no solution from customer support as well :(. I dont have the ticket number handy for the ticket which we raised before mar 18th, the SDL support portal is changed now and old tickets are not visible. As a response to that ticket, they just mentioned that problem could be with specific template and not the product itself, so only we (dev team) need to look at that. :(

Comment: Raised a ticket to customer support - REQ000000031357.. hoping they will help

Comment: To add to Nuno's comment.. w3.org..was just a typo.. and our business content team used http://www. as well..

Comment: hi - while debugging using template builder, its giving the following stacktrace.. and at that particular line, I could see this piece of line: <a href="/views/asp/preview.asp?previewMode=Static&ItemType=16&ItemURI=tcm:15-38040‌​&FromWF=False"